# code to find and print out the list of states that appears more than ten times in the dataset using numpy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using numpy to Find and Print the number of unique states

```
unique,counts = np.unique(data_dict['STATE'],return_counts=True)
print(np.asarray((unique,counts)).T)
```

and i get below output

```
[['ACT' '5']
 ['NSW' '87']
 ['NT' '4']
 ['QLD' '49']
 ['SA' '14']
 ['TAS' '7']
 ['VIC' '54']
 ['WA' '19']]
```

Now how i can find and print out the list of states that appears more than ten times in the dataset.
also state with highest frequency?

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: your counts strings, make a structured array or simple use a where statement to find the indices in the counts > 10, then apply that index to the state array

Comment: print(np.asarray((unique[np.where(counts>10)],counts[np.where(counts>10)])).T)  this should solve it. sorry guys got it.

Comment: `where` is not required: `unique[counts>10]` works just as well.

Comment: @Satpal If you found a solution to your problem, please post it as an answer so that others can benefit from your solution too.

Comment: Thanks @PaulPanzer for the suggestion. updated solution is print(np.asarray((unique[counts>10],counts[counts>10])).T)